# firestore instance shuffles list flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
void getRating() {
firestoreInstance.collection('rating').orderBy('viewed_video', descending: true).getDocuments().then((value) {
  value.documents.forEach((element) {
    print(element.documentID); # Example: Qh5DysX2LpTLvzHZ76shsVOwgAr1, YDWELRqFG0ZV6UHPgB4lJOtDErL2
    firestoreInstance.collection('users').document(element.documentID).get().then((result) {
      print(element.documentID); # Problem: YDWELRqFG0ZV6UHPgB4lJOtDErL2,Qh5DysX2LpTLvzHZ76shsVOwgAr1 
    });
  });
});
}
```

When calling firestore instance again the values are mixed
At first:
Qh5DysX2LpTLvzHZ76shsVOwgAr1, YDWELRqFG0ZV6UHPgB4lJOtDErL2
After:
Ydwelrqfg0zv6uhpgb4ljotderl2,Qh5dysx2lptlvzhz76shsvowgar1
How can I make the list not mix?
Please help:(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing forEach, I suggest you doing map() method like this:

```
value.documents.map((e) => firestoreInstance.collection(`users`).document(e.documentID).get().then((result) {
// do something here
}).toList();
```